# springboot +hazelcast + hibernate's findAll() retrive data from database not cache

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching, spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm currently using hibernate 2nd level cache with **hazelcast 3.7.5** in my springboot application (version 1.5.2.RELEASE). 
Whenever i'm using the findAll() methode implemented by Spring Data Jpa the hibernate retrive the data from the database but when i use findOne(id) method hibernate gets the data from tha chache. Can someone explain this strange behavior?
Here is my hibernate configuration

```
spring:
datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/parametrage;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS PARAM
    username: sa
    password:  
jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming:
            implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
            physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
        hibernate.default_schema: PARAM
        hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
        hibernate.cache.hazelcast.instance_name: hazelcast
        hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
        hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
```

And here is my hazelcast configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching

public class CacheConfiguration {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheConfiguration.class);

private final Environment env;

public CacheConfiguration(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    log.debug("Starting HazelcastCacheManager");
    CacheManager cacheManager = new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
    return cacheManager;
}

@PreDestroy
public void destroy() {
    log.info("Closing Cache Manager");
    Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
}

@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    log.debug("Configuring Hazelcast");
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setInstanceName("hazelcast");
    config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701);
    config.getNetworkConfig().setPortAutoIncrement(true);

    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost").setEnabled(true);

    config.getMapConfigs().put("default", initializeDefaultMapConfig());
    config.getManagementCenterConfig().
    setUrl("http://localhost:8080/mancenter")
    .setEnabled(true);

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}

private MapConfig initializeDefaultMapConfig() {
    MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
mapConfig.setBackupCount(0);

    mapConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);


    mapConfig.setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(0, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_SIZE));

    return mapConfig;
}
}
```

and at last here is an example of an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Banque")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)

public class Banque implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)

@Column(name = "Code")
private Integer code;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 150)
@Column(name = "Designation")
private String designation;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "codeBanque")
@JsonBackReference
private Collection<Societe> societeCollection;

public Banque() {
}

public Banque(Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public Banque(Integer code, String designation) {
    this.code = code;
    this.designation = designation;
}

public Integer getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(Integer code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getDesignation() {
    return designation;
}

public void setDesignation(String designation) {
    this.designation = designation;
}

public Collection<Societe> getSocieteCollection() {
    return societeCollection;
}

public void setSocieteCollection(Collection<Societe> societeCollection) {
    this.societeCollection = societeCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (code != null ? code.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Banque)) {
        return false;
    }
    Banque other = (Banque) object;
    if ((this.code == null && other.code != null) || (this.code != null && !this.code.equals(other.code))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.csys.parametrage.domain.Banque[ code=" + code + " ]";
}
```

}

Comment: You have `use_query_cache` false

Comment: i 'v switched it but still the same problem

Comment: Can you post more details then please ? `pom.xml` plus any other config files such as `hibernate.cfg.xml`, `persistence.xml`.  That or a full reproducing sample would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, like Neil Stevenson said in his comment, to use **query cache**.
To do that i'v switched`hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` to true but also i'v specified to hibernate which queries that must be cached by using `@QueryHints`.
Here is the code of my repository

```
Repository("BanqueRepository")
public interface BanqueRepository extends JpaRepository<Banque, Integer> {

public Banque findByCode(Integer code);

@Override
@QueryHints({
    @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")})
public List<Banque> findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. You need to cache the collection.
I changed

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "codeBanque")
private Collection<Societe> societeCollection;
```

to

```
@Cache (usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "codeBanque")
private Collection<Societe> societeCollection;
```

Comment: My purpose is to get the list of "Banque"

Comment: I fin a solutions thanks to ur first comment :) thank you man :D